# What communication medium must be used between the "parent" process and the "son"?

Tags: mpi

What communication medium must be used between the "parent" process and the "son" processes so that there are no two processes with rank 0? Argue the answer by presenting a program where this is done.
A program must be made in C ++ using MPI functions (DYNAMIC GENERATION OF MPI PROCESSES)
there are no more conditions and explanations, this theme is part of the parallel and distributed programming

Comment: `MPI_Intercomm_merge()`

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is very unclear. You should specify what you mean by "parent" and "son". How did they appear? How do you create them? It is possible to guess what you mean, but the guess can easily be wrong.